# Creating an array of 1000 y values between two know points on a function in python

Tags: python, arrays

So, I wan to create a function where it returns an array of 1000 y values with the condition of an x_0, x_f, the function y(x), and the num points needed 1000, how would I do something like that?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Can you give us an example input and output (truncated)?

Comment: So I want to create the function def valuefinder(x0, xend, Y, num_points=1000), to create an array of 1000 points of Y between x0 and xend on the function Y (something like def Y(x): return x**2), how can I get this function to return this array?

Comment: @YusenYe - perhaps update your question with the details that you've shared on the comment? It would help for whatever efforts / approaches you've taken so far to solve the problem be reflected directly on your question too :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want generalizable code that can handle any Python function, you will need to forfeit NumPy's fast speed using [`np.vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html). Otherwise try to use [universal functions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) whenever possible. With the code below, you can have control via the `vectorize` parameter.

```
def value_finder(start, stop, func, num_points=1000, vectorize=False):
    nums = np.linspace(start, stop, num_points)
    if vectorize:
        func = np.vectorize(func)
    return func(nums)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import random

def y_func(x):
  return (x^2 + 2*x + 1)

def get_1k(x_min, x_max):

  x_out = []

  for i in range(0, 1000):
    x_out.append(y_func(random.randint(x_min, x_max)))
  return x_out

random.seed()
print(get_1k(10, 10000))
```

- `y_func` is a user-defined function that, given an x, returns a y that is computed from it.
- `get_1k()` returns 1000 calculations of y_func between a max and min x. It returns the array of computed values.

Note that this may return duplicate values, and only uses integers. If you want to use floats, use `random.random()`.

[Try it here!](https://repl.it/repls/CautiousCompetentComputer)